# Force return from RunAsync() via decision made in web API Controller in Service Fabric

Tags: service-fabric-stateful, azure-service-fabric

This thread is highly relevant to the scenario when you see exception thrown such as `FabricObjectClosedException`.

The question is for specific scenario when you see the above exception while en-queue using StateManager commit in web api controller upon http-request.

To give more background story, `FabricObjectCloseException` is thrown when the Service Fabric object is currently in a closed state due to one of reasons ([**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.fabricobjectclosedexception?view=azure-dotnet)):

1. The Service Fabric object is being deleted.
2. The Service Fabric object is not reachable due to a failover.

If the above exception were thrown within the `RunAsync()` while loop, the recommended practice could be return out of the `RunAsync()` method, which invokes restart of the service based on the [**link**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.data.itransaction?view=azure-dotnet).

What if the exception was thrown while trying to use reliable state manager in web API controller? How can the `RunAsync()` of the stateful service get out of the while loop in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure that I understand the full picture but I can think of the situations below:

You have:

1. Web API controller that is exposed as `ServiceReplicaListener` to serve incoming requests
2. Some *background / continues* work done in the `RunAsync` method

The **first thing** here is to check whether `CancellationToken` passed to `RunAsync` is set when `FabricObjectCloseException` is thrown.

As far as I understand `FabricObjectCloseException` is thrown when replica is being shutdown ([here](https://olegkarasik.wordpress.com/2018/10/03/service-fabric-handbook/#reliable-services-stateful-service-life-cycle-shutdown) I once had described the steps Service Fabric performs when service is shutdown) by Cluster Manager or by some other reasons. If this assumption is true then `CancellationToken` should be set.

If passed `CancellationToken` isn't set - then I could advice you to:

1. Create a simple service that wraps `CancellationTokenSource`
2. Create instance of `CancellationTokenSource` inside the constructor of `StatefulService` class and initialize a service from #1.
3. Using dependency injection, inject this service in Web API controller and signal cancellation when `FabricObjectCloseException` occurs.
4. In `RunAsync`, check the cancellation status of both: passed `CancellationToken` and custom service.

P.S. I am not sure about what kind of work you do in the `RunAsync` method but I just want to mention that it is OK to `return` from `RunAsync` when the background part of the work is done - or to even not override it when there is no background work.

Comment: My only concern is when role changes among replicas or some how the DI injection contains stale reference can this design dynamically handle pointing to the correct primary replica? could there be such scenario or would DI injection be able to handle all cases?

Comment: When replica changes roles the `CreateReplicaListeners` method is called. You can initialize the service from #1 with new `CancellationTokenSource` inside this method.